# How to accept two parameter in inbuilt constructor function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

here i have my this code

```
// creating objects using builtin construcor functions
let account = new Function ('uname ' , `this.username=uname;
                        username = uname;
                        password = upass;
                        this.print = function(){
                            console.log(this.username, this.password);
                        }`);
let LoginAct = new account('deva', 'deva');
LoginAct.print();
```

Here I have created an constructor function named account using builtin function **Function()** . Now here I want to accept two parameter to the object where 1st one is **uname** and second one is **upass** . i tried doing so by writing something like this :- `` let account = new Function ('uname ' , 'upass',  `this.username=uname;... ``

And also like this:- `` let account = new Function ('uname , upass',  `this.username=uname;... ``

but it didnt worked!, Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt (`new Function('param1', 'param2', 'function body')`) should work. The issue is that you don't set `this.password`. So when you call `LoginAct.print()` `this.password` is `undefined`.

```js
// creating objects using builtin construcor functions
let account = new Function ('uname', 'upass', `
  this.username = uname;
  this.password = upass; // <- set this.password
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(this.username, this.password);
  }
`);
let LoginAct = new account('deva', 'deva');
LoginAct.print();
```

Comment: thank you, I forgot to point those variables. thank you so much for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like code like this

```js
// creating objects using builtin construcor functions
let Account = function(uname, upass) {
  this.username = uname;
  this.password = upass;
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(this.username, this.password);
  }
};
let loginAct = new Account('deva', 'deva');
loginAct.print();
```

Comment: I know this one. But learning more doesn't harms. No doubts the one you suggested is best, But I wanted to learn that too. who knows where it could help me out.